# android studio Not run in windows 8

Tags: java, android

I tried to install Android Studio, but I'm getting this error when I try to start it:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class D:.gradle-2.2.1
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: You could try installing java 7.

Comment: Did you read the guide that is linked in the message?